# How to change images of each div individually?

Tags: html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <title>Javascript Create Div Element Dynamically</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            .ex
            {
                width:200px;
                position: relative;
                background-color :#CCC;
                height:150px;
                padding:10px;
                margin:5px;
                left-margin:0px;
                float :left;
            }
            #newdiv
            {
                width:800px;
                height:800px;
                border:1px solid #000;      
            }
            .myimage
            {
                height: 80;
                width: 80;
                top:100;
                margin:5px;
            }
            .border
            {
                border:1px solid #000;  
            }

        </style>
        <script>

            cc = 1;
            function changeimage()
            {
                if (cc == 0)
                {
                    cc = 1;
                    $('.myimage').attr('src', 'images/plus.png');
                }
                else if (cc == 1)
                {
                    cc = 2;
                    $('.myimage').attr('src', 'images/plus2.png');
                }
                else if (cc == 2)
                {
                    cc = 3;
                    $('.myimage').attr('src', 'images/plus2.png');
                }
                else
                {
                    cc = 0;
                    $('.myimage').attr('src', 'images/plus2.png');
                }
            }
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            var i = 0;
            function createDiv()
            {

                if (i < 6) {
                    var divTag = document.createElement("div");

                    divTag.id = "div1";

                    divTag.setAttribute("align", "left");

                    divTag.style.margin = "0px auto";

                    divTag.className = "ex";

                    divTag.innerHTML = "<img class='myimage' onclick='changeimage()' border='0' src='images/white_contact.png' width='100' height='180' />";

                    document.getElementById("newdiv").appendChild(divTag)

                }

                i++;
                $(".ex").draggable({containment: 'parent', cursor: 'pointer', opacity: 0.6});
                $(".ex").droppable({hoverClass: 'border'});

            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <p align="left">
            <b>Click this button to create div element dynamically:</b>
            <input id="btn1" type="button" value="create div" onClick="createDiv();" />

        <div id = "newdiv">

        </div>
    </p>

</body>
</html>
```

after I add the 6 DIV, I click on one DIV, all images will change, now I want to change the image of each div individually, I am running out of time. Can somebody show me which part goes wrong, and let me the solution, thanks

Comment: make it different names so you can specific choose wich image you want to change? Just an idea though! :)

Comment: You need to make the ID attribute unique for each div.  If every new DIV has the same ID, that defeats the purpose of actually using the ID attribute.  ID should always be unique.

Comment: can show me some example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify the code so that just the img element clicked gets its source image changed, rather than all the img elements in the 'myimage' class. I'd suggest passing the img element to changeimage as a parameter:

```
divTag.innerHTML = "<img class='myimage' onclick='changeimage(this)' border='0' src='images/white_contact.png' width='100' height='180' />";
```

so that you can then select just the clicked image:

```
function changeimage(image)
{
if (cc==0) 
  {
  cc=1;
  $(image).attr('src', 'images/plus.png');
  }
// etc
```

There's a bit more work involved in ensuring that your click counts are done on a per img basis, rather than globally. One way of doing that is by putting the counts on the img elements themselves, e.g. as `image.cc` rather than just `cc` inside `changeimage` (although you'd need to be a bit careful about the case were `image.cc` being undefined).